# How to do interpolation to calculate the temporal trend of temperature using 50 climate stations data in R?

Tags: r

I want to convert long time series data of temperature, rainfall to monthly and want to interpolate and compute the temporal trend for a country using 90 meteorological stations. 
Data format is like

Year Month Day Rain MaxT MinT
    1 1970 1 1 0.0 23.0 -99.9
    2 1970 1 2 0.0 23.0 -99.9
    3 1970 1 3 0.0 23.0 -99.9
    4 1970 1 4 0.0 24.0 -99.9
    5 1970 1 5 0.0 23.0 -99.9
    6 1970 1 6 0.0 23.0 -99.9
    7 1970 1 7 0.0 23.0 -99.9

Comment: Please learn to format your text.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I am new to programming and just learning simple things.